# Traversing decision tree to get rule set

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, weka, decision-tree

I am generating ML decision tree using train data. As per my use case I need to look into the decision tree to get more details about data distribution like values at each nodes etc. I have used weka in java to generate the tree and I can see the tree structure using simple print statement, however weka doesn't provide any API to look further into tree, tree is just available as String. I don't want to parse the string, is there any other library available which can help in translating trees into set of rules by normal traversing?
Any other ML based library which can generate tree based on data available and let you peek into tree for analysis like rule extraction?

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("NewData.arff"));

        Instances data = new Instances(reader);
        reader.close();
        data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);
        String[] options = new String[1];
        options[0] = "-U";            // unpruned tree
        J48 tree = new J48();         // new instance of tree
        tree.setOptions(options);     // set the options
        tree.setMinNumObj(100);
        tree.buildClassifier(data);   // build classifier
        System.out.println(tree);   // Print tree as string
```

Now I want to peek into the tree to get some results. Please help me with any available library for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Weka is open-source.

Use the source. Customize as necessary.

If you absolutely need access to some internal data structures (beware that these may change across versions) it is legit to make them public. Or you could even make an API to traverse the tree (if this *really* does not exist yet; because there exist functions to visualize th tree, too) and then *contribute  to Weka* so that others can use it, too.